# When debugging Swift code, can I get a typed reference to an object given just its address?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, swift, lldb

When debugging Objective-C code in LLDB, I often create variables that refer to objects in memory using just their address. For example:

```
(lldb) po self.view
<UIView: 0x7ff5f7a18430; frame = (0 64; 320 504); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ff5f7a192e0>>
(lldb) e CALayer* $layer = (CALayer*) 0x7ff5f7a192e0
(lldb) e $layer.borderWidth
(CGFloat) $17 = 0
```

Given just an object's type and its address in memory, I'm able to inspect and manipulate it.

Is this impossible when debugging Swift code?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
(lldb) e let $layer = unsafeBitCast(0x7fd120f474b0, CALayer.self)
```

Comment: `unsafeBitCast` is even cooler. How did you find out about these APIs? None of them seem to be in the docs.

Comment: @Bill I found them by poking around the Swift standard library header (Command+Click on a standard library function or symbol) .  All of the interesting functions and classes have "Unsafe" in their name or comments.

Comment: I posted the updated lldb expression that got me started on Xcode 7.3 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441418/lldb-swift-casting-raw-address-into-usable-type/38905566#38905566

Comment: In Swift 3: `e  let $layer = unsafeBitCast(0x7fd120f474b0, to: CALayer.self)`