# LLDB (Swift): Casting Raw Address into Usable Type

Tags: ios, swift, lldb

Is there an LLDB command that can cast a raw address into a usable Swift class?

For example:

```
(lldb) po 0x7df67c50 as MKPinAnnotationView
```

I know that this address points to a MKPinAnnotationView, but it is not in a frame that I can select. But, I want to cast the raw address into a MKPinAnnotationView so that I can examine its properties. Is this possible?

Answer (score 216, accepted):

Under Xcode 8.2.1 and Swift 3, the lldb command ***po*** or ***p*** won't work with the typed variable. You will need to use the swift command ***print*** to examine the properties of the typed object instance.  (Thanks to [cbowns's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41904530/4915444)!) E.g.:

```
expr -l Swift -- import UIKit
expr -l Swift -- let $pin = unsafeBitCast(0x7df67c50, to: MKPinAnnotationView.self)
expr -l Swift -- print($pin.alpha)
```

Comment: This really shouldn't be so hard

Comment: This was a little counter intuitive. I thought I didn't need to type the `(lldb)` in my console. But it didn't work without that.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in objective-c?

Comment: I keep getting back at this. I probably should create a lldb alias for `expr -l Swift -- `..

Comment: As was mentioned in a different answer to this question, typing `settings set target.language swift` once is enough to avoid `expr -l Swift -- ` in subsequent commands.

Comment: I was just passing by and wanted to share my little observation with you: the `print` function is redundant there! it will print `() $R0 = {}` which means that expression executed and return nothing. Well I personally have no idea where it was printed, but not in this stupid debugger. So you should write just `expr -l Swift -- $pin.alpha` to see its value on next line

Answer (score 60):

You can use Swift's `unsafeBitCast` function to cast an address to an object instance:

```
(lldb) e let $pin = unsafeBitCast(0x7df67c50, MKPinAnnotationView.self)
(lldb) po $pin
```

Then you can work with `$pin` as usual – access properties, call methods, etc.

Check out this article for more information: [Swift Memory Dumping](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-08-29-swift-memory-dumping.html).

Comment: For the first statement i think you forgot the 'expr' or 'expression'. Otherwise it is working great!

Comment: I'm getting "error: use of undeclared identifier 'unsafeBitCast'" in Xcode 7.2.

Comment: Besides that error (@devios) there's another error it shows in 7.3.1: "error: unknown type name 'let'"

Comment: Note that depending on context you might need to switch lldb to Swift mode first using `(lldb) settings set target.language swift`. Also, in some cases (e.g. when breaking outside of your app's module while casting to a type from your app) you might need to follow that with a `e import MyApp`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for tagged pointers. Short NSString, NSIndexPath, NSNumber etc. are implemented as tagged pointers where the content is part of the pointer itself.

Answer (score 28):

The lldb format for `expression` seems to have changed in Xcode 7.3. The following got me started:

```
(lldb) expr -l Swift -- import UIKit
(lldb) expr -l Swift -- let $view = unsafeBitCast(0x7fb75d8349c0, UIView.self)
```

Answer (score 23):

For Custom Classes you need to import your project

```
expr -l Swift -- import MyTestProject
expr -l Swift -- let $vc = unsafeBitCast(0x7fad22c066d0, ViewController.self)
expr -l Swift -- print($vc.view)
```

Comment: I'm getting error: no such module "MyProjectName". Any thoughts how to fix this?

Comment: @AlexanderStepanishin try setting the thread/stack path, Example: "MyApp > Thread 1 > 12 main"

Comment: @AlexanderStepanishin you need to hit a breakpoint. It won't work if you interrupt the flow by pressing the Debug Memory Graph button in xCode.

Answer (score 22):

Objective-C version

```
po ((MKPinAnnotationView *)0x7df67c50).alpha
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. In my case I was in the `Debug View Hierarchy` view, right clicked on a view, then selected `Print description of...`. That gave me a memory address and type I could drop into the code above. Nice to know that the visual debugger puts the console into an Obj-C frame.

Answer (score 13):

As of Xcode 8/Swift 3, here's what worked for me. (This is based off [@sfaxon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38905566/).)

```
(lldb) expr -l Swift -- import UIKit
(lldb) expr -l Swift -- let $nav = unsafeBitCast(0x1030ff000, to: UINavigationController.self)
```

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to all the answers above, ***unsafeBitCast*** also works well with Xcode 8.3.2 / Swift 3 / macOS / Cocoa Application.

Memorize an address of current instance

```
(lldb) p tabView.controlTint
(NSControlTint) $R10 = defaultControlTint

(lldb) p self
(LearningStoryboard.NSTabViewController) $R11 = 0x00006080000e2280 {
.....
```

Later, examine them

```
(lldb) p unsafeBitCast(0x00006080000e2280, to: NSTabViewController.self).tabView.controlTint
(NSControlTint) $R20 = graphiteControlTint

(lldb) p $R11.tabView.controlTint
(NSControlTint) $R21 = graphiteControlTint
```

If something like this happens

```
(lldb) p unsafeBitCast(0x00006080000e2280, to: NSTabViewController.self).tabView.controlTint
error: use of undeclared identifier 'to'

(lldb) p $R11.tabView.controlTint 
error: use of undeclared identifier '$R11'
```

make sure that choose one of the stack frames of Swift source code rather than assembler one.

It is likely to happen when the application was paused by clicking a ***Pause*** button or stopped with an exception. By choosing a stack frame accordingly, let ***lldb*** infer a proper programing language.

Answer (score 8):

It took me longer to figure out that I'd like to admit. It's similar to @afinlayson answer, but with better explanation (I hope!) and fixed syntax

If you want to check properties of an objects using Xcode’s view hierarchy debugger then this will work: 
You’re in objc context by default so you’ll have to switch it to Swift context

1. First import your project (if you want to use some of the classes defined there)

`expr -l Swift -- import <YOUR PROJECT NAME>`

2. Cast object using it’s memory address to whatever class you want

`expr -l Swift -- let $vc = unsafeBitCast(0x7fb7c51cb270, to: <YOUR PROJECT NAME>.<YOUR CUSTOM CLASS NAME>.self)`

3. Access any value you want from the object

`expr -l Swift -- print($vc.<PROPERTY NAME>)`

**Example:**

`expr -l Swift -- import Football`

`expr -l Swift -- let $vc = unsafeBitCast(0x7fb7c51cb270, to: Football.Ball.self)`

`expr -l Swift -- print($vc.velocity)`

Answer (score 7):

[@Xi Chen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42766226/3379766) works perfectly when your LLDB session was started in a Swift context. However, in some cases you might have stopped in a breakpoint *outside* a Swift context; for example, when it's a symbolic breakpoint to Objective-C API, or when in Debug View Hierarchy mode (at least as of Xcode 11.4).

```
error: unknown type name 'let'
error: use of undeclared identifier 'unsafeBitCast'
```

In that case, you'll need to do it the old way using Objective-C:

```
e MKPinAnnotationView *$pin = (MKPinAnnotationView *)0x7df67c50
```

and now you can use `$pin` as you would.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way, swift 4

```
expr unsafeBitCast(0x7df67c50, to: MKPinAnnotationView.self)
```

Answer (score 3):

`po` is an alias, which means it can be overridden. You can override `po` by handling hex addresses using objc:

```
command regex po
s/(0x[[:xdigit:]]+)/expression -l objc -O -- %1/
s/(.+)/expression -O -- %1/
```

To see what effect this has, you can tell lldb to expand these aliases:

```
(lldb) settings set interpreter.expand-regex-aliases true
```

Also I have created https://github.com/kastiglione/swift_po, which is a substitute `po` for Swift. It handles object addresses, and has a few other improvements too.

Comment: from your link, `expression -l objc -O -- 0x76543210` is just the response for me, and it doesn't need to know the variable class from the adress!

Answer (score 1):

When in Swift lldb context and dealing with `NSObject` subclass such as `MKPinAnnotationView` it's arguably easier to deliberately switch back to obj-c lldb context using this 1-liner:

```
e -O -l objc -- 0x7df67c50
```

where `e -O --` is equivalent to `po` in lldb when in obj-c context.