# lldb inspection of swift variables within dynamic framework

Tags: ios, swift

I am unable to inspect variable state within dynamic frameworks in the lldb debugging console.  I am able to inspect the same code when I add it to the main application.  Why is this?  Is there a workaround?  Any ideas?

```
(lldb) po URLSessionDataTask
error: <EXPR>:1:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'URLSessionDataTask'
URLSessionDataTask
^
```

[image: Code sample]
[image: Inspection console output]

Comment: I often have similar issues. In my case, it appears to happen because the library needs non-standard header search paths to build and LLDB can't parse the module correctly because of that. You can see if that works by running [`p @import LibraryName`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH4-SW10) in the lldb console, and looking at the results.

Comment: Does not look to good:

`(lldb) p @import BDModules
error: <EXPR>:1:2: error: expected an attribute name
@import BDModules
 ^`

Comment: Are you using Xcode 6.3?

Comment: I am using Xcode 6.3

Comment: Well, that's weird; it's not even a module load error, it just didn't get what you asked for.

Comment: If you are interested in looking further, here is a link to the workspace: https://github.com/banDedo/BDModules.

It is nested in the `Harness` directory.  Must run pod install first to install development pods.

I specifically set a breakpoint on line 155 of `APISessionManager.swift` and launch app/login to see issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation. I could create a class instant of anything in the main app but nothing in the dynamic libraries, when it was Swift code.

```
(lldb) exp let $a = RustyAppInfo()  //class from framework
error: <EXPR>:3:10: error: use of unresolved identifier 'RustyAppInfo'
```

Fix for me:

```
(lldb) expr -- import rusty_nails //framework name
(lldb) exp let $a = RustyAppInfo()
```

My lldb version: `902.0.79.7`.  Notice, lldb knew I was trying to write swift code. In an iOS app, where you have Swift and Objective-C code, I always find it useful to type:

`(lldb) settings set target.language swift`

Answer was inspired by [LLDB (Swift): Casting Raw Address into Usable Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441418/lldb-swift-casting-raw-address-into-usable-type)