# LLDB error: unknown type name 'let', Xcode 8.1

Tags: swift3, lldb, xcode8

I am trying to unsafe cast an UIImageView in LLDB. I am getting the error: unknown type name 'let'. Here is a screen shot [error: unknown type name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ko6UD.png)

I have tried importing UIkit

```
expr -l Swift -- import UIKit
```

but it does not fix the issue.

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/38905566/1187415. – And it is `.self`, not `.safe`

Comment: Comparison has been made before posting the question, hence the mention of expr -l Swift -- import UIKit  not working.

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like you are trying to evaluate a swift expression when not stopped in a Swift frame.  lldb guesses the appropriate language to use for expressions from the language of the current frame.  If this were C then "let" is in the position to be a type name, making sense of the error.

What happens if you do:

(lldb) expr -l swift --

You can force all expressions to be run as swift expressions using:

(lldb) settings set target.language swift

if that suits your purposes better.

Comment: `(lldb) expr -l swift --`
`Enter expressions, then terminate with an empty line to evaluate:`
`1` I do not know what happened but after restarting the application I can not replicate the problem.