# How do I print property of object with given address in LLDB?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, lldb

I know `po 0x12345` can print the description of the object, but if I wanna print its property

( for example property **frame** of the object at **0x12345** ),

How could I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LLDB (Swift): Casting Raw Address into Usable Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441418/lldb-swift-casting-raw-address-into-usable-type)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Cast it to the object type. Example:

```
po ((UIView *) 0x12345).layer
```