# What's a proper way to print variable with a hex pointer given (Xcode 10.3, 11 betas)

Tags: lldb

Given the infamous
       < NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c809d970 UIView:0x11fe288b0.height == 16   (active)> & co from the autolayout engine

what's the brave new swiftly world way to print an object of UIView class by a hex pointer value?

> (lldb) p *((UIView*)0x11fe288b0)

error: :3:12: error: expected ',' separator
*((UIView*)0x11fe288b0)
           ^
           ,

> (lldb) po *((UIView*)0x11fe288b0)

error: :3:12: error: expected ',' separator
*((UIView*)0x11fe288b0)
           ^
           ,

> (lldb) expr *((UIView*)0x11fe288b0)

error: :3:12: error: expected ',' separator
*((UIView*)0x11fe288b0)
           ^
           ,

This is in xcode 10.3 and 11 beta 3

UPD:

> (lldb) p *((UIView*)0x11fe288b0)

worked at first in xcode 11 beta 5, now it ceased to work:
this might have been fixed in beta 5 but possibly
that fix got clobbered when I went back to xcode 10.3 that "installed
additional components"

UPD2: this seems to be a duplicate of [Xcode debugger (lldb) get object description from memory address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45463132/xcode-debugger-lldb-get-object-description-from-memory-address/45464836#45464836)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the problem is just layout constraints, the simplest solution is to give your constraint a string identifier. You can do that in code or in the storyboard. Makes debugging constraints really easy; the identifier appears in quotes first thing in the debug output:

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003af86e0 'getStartedBad' ... >",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003af8730 'getStartedTop' ... >"
)
```

If the question is about a UIView for which you have only the address, you can send messages to it like this:

```
(lldb) expr -l objc -O -- [(UIView*)0x11fe288b0 layer]
```

(Yes, you have to talk Objective-C to it, but I don't think there's any other way.)

Comment: In general there is this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45464836/341994 but you already know these are constraints

Comment: pardon my ignorance by how do you give a string identifier to a view in code?

Comment: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57109674/how-do-i-change-names-to-tell-apart-uiviews-in-xcode-visual-debugger I've added bounty for that programmatic identifier question

Comment: Oh, I see, you want to identify the view, not the layout constraint.

Comment: But you see what I do is give the layout constraint an identifier that identifies the view it affects. It’s just a name so you pack it with information.

Comment: Constraints identification is also useful to tell between dozens of them at a glance.

Comment: I expanded my answer to be a bit more helpful.

Comment: What I don't see is a property to set a name or identifier here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutanchor

Comment: how to you get that getStartedTop to a constraint created programmatically?

Comment: By setting the constraint's `identifier` when I create the constraint programmatically.

Comment: rg8t success. I see that prop added in ios7. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: "What I don't see is a property to set a name or identifier here" Because an anchor is not a constraint.

Comment: right, found it, gave you the rightfully deservedbounty in another bountied question that this discussion really belongs to

Answer (score 6):

You can cast from an address to a UIView (or mutatis mutandis for any other class) in Swift using unsafeBitCast like:

```
(lldb) po unsafeBitCast(<ADDRESS>, to: UIView.self)
```

You can also access properties this way:

```
(lldb) po unsafeBitCast(<ADDRESS>, to: UIView.self).bounds
```

etc...

Comment: (lldb) po unsafeBitCast(0x1021a8410, to: UIView.self)
error: use of undeclared identifier 'to'

Comment: That's odd.  "to:" has been the name for the type parameter in unsafeBitCast since at least swift4.0.   If you can repro this in a small example, please file a bug with http://bugs.swift.org.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I get the same error you showed if I run this expression in a C frame, since that's the best the C parser can do with the expression.  lldb chooses the default language for expressions from the language of the currently selected frame.  If you are in a C-frame, use the expression from the previous answer.  Only use this one if a swift frame is the currently selected one.