# Printing Object description at a specific memory adress

Tags: swift, xcode

In Xcode's debugging console, it is possible to check the memory address of an object. For exemple, if I set a break point in a ViewController :

`po self`
would return something like `<ViewController: 0x600003eb1f00>`

Is it possible to do the opposite? Giving a memory address, find the description of the Object associated with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with that command line (accessing view property in this example :

```
expr -l objc -O -- [(UIViewController*)0x600003eb1f00 view]
```

You can find a similar question (and answer) here [What's a proper way to print variable with a hex pointer given (Xcode 10.3, 11 betas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57265331/whats-a-proper-way-to-print-variable-with-a-hex-pointer-given-xcode-10-3-11-b)