# How can I cast, inspect pointers given back from the view debug hierarchy?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, lldb, view-debugging

I keep getting errors of

> hexadecimal floating literal requires an exponent

or if I try to cast some label pointer, e.g. do:

```
po 0x7ffded7e7cf0 as UIlabel
```

I get:

> error: expected ';' after expression
>
> error: unknown type name 'as'

[image: View Hierarchy debugger with right panel open and console with error]

I know I can see most of this information on the right panel, but I want to get the information from the console myself (e.g. a label's text).

Comment: "po" seems to like classic Objective-C syntax.  Does `po [0x... backgroundColor]` work for you?

Comment: Hah! It worked!

Comment: This **2nd** solution from [LLDB (Swift): Casting Raw Address into Usable Type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42766226/5175709) **did** work when I had it stopped using the view debugger. Other answers didn't work.  Also Philiips easy peasy solution  `po [0x7ffded7e7cf0 text]` worked like a charm. Would you care to  elaborate about your deleted comment as to why you thought it won't work when view debug hierarchy is running? I don't know about their conflicts, what you can or can't do. Is there any good document on that?

Comment: @Honey I deleted my comment since I think that it and this question is an exact duplicate.