# Create Swift class instance variable with lldb, versus Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, lldb

Using my debugger (lldb) I can easily create Instances classes when it is Objective-C code.

```
(lldb) e id $my_hello = [hello_from_objc new]
(lldb) po $my_hello
<hello_from_objc: 0x1c4013020>
(lldb) po [$my_hello secret_objc_method]
0x000000000000002a
(lldb) po (int) [$my_hello secret_objc_method]
42
```

But I can't work out how to do the same with lldb's expression command when the code is pure Swift.  I create an instance in Swift code easily enough..

```
let my_swift_framework = Hello_Class()
print("✔️ \(my_swift_framework.samplePublicVariable)")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example: After executing the Swift code

```
class HelloClass {
    func hello() {
        print("hello")
    }
}
```

you can create an object in the debugger window:

```
(lldb) expression let $myHello = HelloClass()
(lldb) po $myHello
<hello_class: 0x101121180>

(lldb) po $myHello.hello()
hello
```

If you get an error

```
error: unknown type name 'let'
error: use of undeclared identifier 'HelloClass'
```

then set the expression language to Swift explicitly:

```
(lldb) expression -l swift -o -- let $myHello = HelloClass()

(lldb) expression -l swift -o -- $myHello.hello()
```

Or you can change the lldb language context back to Swift:

`(lldb) settings set target.language swift`

Comment: In both the C and Swift lldb expression parsers, an initial $ is used as the "namespace" indicator for lldb persistent variables.  That keeps them out of the way of program variables.  Variables made in lldb expressions  w/o an initial $ are local to the expression.

Comment: this didn't work for me.  (error: unknown type name 'let',error: use of undeclared identifier 'HelloClass' - even though it was in the symbol table).  

I tried connecting to the app in debug mode with xCode and lldb on the command line with lldb.

I also tried this article:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441418/lldb-swift-casting-raw-address-into-usable-type

Comment: @rustyMagnet: I tested this with a command-line app, running directly from Xcode. I am afraid that I do not have a better solution  currently.

Comment: @MartinR I have found the answer. It seems something is setting the lldb expression -l automatically after the appDelegate runs.

Comment: @rustyMagnet: So `-l swift` did help finally? Glad that you solved the problem! – (But note that Swifts naming conventions are quite different from (e.g.) Python, all identifiers use camel case – upper camel case for types, lower camel case for everything else :)

Comment: thanks @MartinR.  Yeah, I thought you might spot that.  I was being inconsistent on my case so I just went back to camel case...